# openGate job cannot submit to the remote machine by HTcondor

Tags: condor

I have installed htcondor cluster for my three machines. However, when I try to run the htcondor to submit my GATE jobs I get the following error:
condor_exec.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libG4Tree.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

The libG4Tree.so is in my geant4install/lib and I installed geant4 for every machines. Also, I source geant4.sh in all machines.
The following is my condor script:

```
Executable     = $GC_EXEC                                                   
universe       = vanilla
getenv = True
#Requirements   = Memory >= 512 && Arch =="INTEL"     
#Rank       = Memory >= 512
#Image_Size     = 28 Meg     

#GJS PART => DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE ANYTHING FROM THIS POINT ON
#INCLUDING THESE COMMENT LINES!!                                                                       
Arguments      = $GC_MACRO                                              
Input   = $GC_EXEC.in1
Output  = $GC_EXEC.out1                                                     
Error   = $GC_EXEC.err1
Log     = $GC_EXEC.log1
Queue
```

I don't know where the error comes from. Does anyone has some ideas? Please help.

Comment: Is `geant4.sh` sourced in the actual running job? HTCondor jobs start with a fresh environment by default. `getenv = True` after sourcing on the submit machine may not point to the right paths on your execute nodes, because it's copying environment variables that were created on the submit machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Josh. I solved it today by changing the enviroment in my submit machine to match the envroment in the execute machine. What's more, I found that I didn't create the shared file system so the execute machine couldn't find the inputs.